# Run Protractor against multiple app server parallel

Tags: node.js, protractor

I need to reduce the run time of my Protractor tests, so i want them to run parallel on multiple app servers.
Protractor can by multiCapabilities to open multiple instances of webdriver,
but for all of them the "baseUrl" is the same.
In my application, 2 suites that run at the same time against same app server, can influence each other.
So i need a way to manage a queue of "baseUrl"s and every suite that start to run will get another baseUrl from that queue. And i want to be sure that if 2 test ask for baseUrl from the queue at the same time, they will get 2 different url's and not the same one.
Can someone give me a direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `protractor.conf.js`, you can set baseUrl to be the result of a self-executing function:

```
exports.config = {
  baseUrl: function() {
      //write some code to generate a unique URL
  }();
};
```

reference config: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js